# Seeking help on a macro \DefineOperator

Tags: macros, expl3, math-operators

I'm trying to build a command `\DefineOperator` for defining multiple operators at one time, which can be used like this:

```
\DefineOperator { ord, card, car, disc }
\DefineOperator { id, Id, Ker, Image = Im } [ style = \mathsf ]
\DefineOperator*{ Lim, Max, Min } [ style = \mathsf ]
\DefineOperator { Set, Mat, Grp, Top } [ style = \mathbf ]
```

Currently, the basic interface works, but its option `style = ...` is a little problematic: I don't know how to pass the *value* instead the macro itself of `\l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl` to `\DeclareMathOperator`, so all the operators are sharing the last specified style. How to fix this behavior?

Besides, I think my usage of `\exp_after:wN` or `\exp_args:Ne` to `\DeclareMathOperator` is quite inelegant, but cannot come up with a better idea. Do you have any suggestion on this?

Below is a MWE. Thanks in advance for any help~

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_warning:nnn { nne }

\msg_new:nnn { projlib-math }
  { operator-not-define }
  { The~math~operator~"#1"~cannot~be~defined,~a~command~with~the~same~name~has~already~existed. }

\tl_new:N \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl
\keys_define:nn { projlib-math-operator }
  {
    , style        .tl_set:N     = \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl
    , unknown      .code:n       = {}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn
% #1 is a bool for star or empty
% #2 is a list of operators
% #3 is the option
  {
    \keys_set:nn { projlib-math-operator } { #3 }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { = }
          {
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { = } { ##1 }
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
              {
                \msg_warning:nne  { projlib-math } { operator-not-define } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
              }
              {
                \bool_if:NTF #1
                  {
                    \exp_after:wN \DeclareMathOperator \exp_after:wN * \exp_after:wN  { \cs:w \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } \cs_end: } { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } } }
                  }
                  {
                    \exp_args:Ne \DeclareMathOperator { \cs:w \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } \cs_end: } { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } } }
                  }
              }
          }
          {
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { ##1 }
              {
                \msg_warning:nnn  { projlib-math } { operator-not-define } { ##1 }
              }
              {
                \bool_if:NTF #1
                  {
                    \exp_after:wN \DeclareMathOperator \exp_after:wN * \exp_after:wN  { \cs:w ##1 \cs_end: } { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl { ##1 } }
                  }
                  {
                    \exp_args:Ne \DeclareMathOperator { \cs:w ##1 \cs_end: } { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl { ##1 } }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \DefineOperator { s O{} m O{} }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
      {
        \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
      }
      {
        \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { #3 } { #2 }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\DefineOperator { id, Id, Ker, Image = Im } [ style = \mathsf ]

\DefineOperator*{ Lim, Max } [ style = \mathbf ]


\begin{document}

\( \id_A \)

\( \Lim_{n\to \infty} \)

\[
  \Lim_{n\to \infty}
\]

\[
  \Max_A
\]

\( \Id_A, \Image \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: The name of categories are *not* operators.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set up different key families for the style and for the evaluation.

An indirect approach is taken: the mandatory argument is absorbed as key-values, where all keys are unknown. The corresponding code populates a property list that can be mapped. Each property has the desired command name as key and the desired symbol as value (or nothing).

At the end we can test whether the value is empty and use the key for both the command name and the symbol.

With two suitable variants of the auxiliary function we can expand the `style` (if not empty).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineOperator}{ s O{} m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { projlib-math-operator } { style=, #2 }
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { * } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\prop_new:N \l__projlib_math_operator_prop

\keys_define:nn { projlib-math-operator }
 {
  style .tl_set:N = \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl,
 }
\keys_define:nn { projlib-math-operator-aux }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \prop_put:NVn \l__projlib_math_operator_prop \l_keys_key_str { #1 },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l__projlib_math_operator_prop
  \keys_set:nn { projlib-math-operator-aux } { #3 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l__projlib_math_operator_prop
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { ##2 }
     {
      \__projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { ##1 } { ##1 }
     }
     {
      \__projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { ##1 } { ##2 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__projlib_math_define_operator:nnn
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl
   {% no style
    \__projlib_math_define_operator_aux:cnn { #2 } { #3 } { #1 }
   }
   {% style
    \__projlib_math_define_operator_aux:con { #2 } { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl { #3 } } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__projlib_math_define_operator_aux:Nnn
 {% #1 is the command
  % #2 is the desired symbol
  % #3 is either * or empty
  \DeclareMathOperator #3 #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__projlib_math_define_operator_aux:Nnn { cnn, con }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineOperator { ord, card, car, disc }
\DefineOperator [style=\mathsf]{ id, Id, Ker, Image = Im }
\DefineOperator*[style=\mathsf]{ Lim, Max, Min }
\DefineOperator [style=\mathbf]{ Set, Mat, Grp, Top }

\begin{document}

$\ord\card\car\disc\id\Id\Ker\Image\Lim\Max\Min\Set\Mat\Grp\Top$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Mathematical note. I left the last group, but the symbols for categories are *not* operators. They should be ordinary symbols.

Comment: Thank you for this! It would take me some time to understand your code since I haven't encountered property list before. Two quick questions: 1) In `Image = Im`, the resulted `Im` should have the style `\mathsf`, but instead it is just `\mathrm`, how should this be fixed? 2) In general how is one supposed to typeset the symbols for categories?

Comment: @Jinwen I fixed the code to correctly apply the chosen style. The symbol for categories are ordinary symbols: just `\mathbf{Set}` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is to be considered more elegant, but you can, e.g., use cascades of expressions of pattern

```
\exp_args:Nn⟨expansion-type⟩ \use:n 
                             {⟨tokens not to be touched by the \exp_args:Nn..-command⟩} 
                             {⟨tokens to be expanded according to expansion-type⟩}
```

, whereby both `⟨tokens not to be touched by the \exp_args:Nn..-command⟩` and `⟨tokens to be expanded according to expansion-type⟩` can also contain such expressions.

This way you can have (components of) (nested) macro arguments expanded/extracted according to your needs:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { projlib-math }
  { operator-not-define }
  { The~math~operator~"#1"~cannot~be~defined,~a~command~with~the~same~name~has~already~existed. }

\tl_new:N \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl
\keys_define:nn { projlib-math-operator }
  {
    , style        .tl_set:N     = \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl
    , unknown      .code:n       = {}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn
  % #1 is a bool for star or empty
  % #2 is a list of operators
  % #3 is the option
  {
    \keys_set:nn { projlib-math-operator } { #3 }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { = }
          {
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { = } { ##1 }
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
              {
                \exp_args:Nne  \use:n 
                               { \msg_warning:nnn  { projlib-math } { operator-not-define } } 
                               { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
              }
              {
                \bool_if:NTF #1
                  {
                    \exp_args:Nnf \use:n 
                                  { \exp_args:Nnc \use:n {\DeclareMathOperator*} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } }
                  }
                  {
                    \exp_args:Nnf \use:n 
                                  { \exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathOperator { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } }
                  }
                  % This is the f-argument of  \exp_args:Nnf :
                  { \exp_args:Nne  \use:n 
                                   { \exp_args:NnV \use:nn 
                                                   { \exp_stop_f: } 
                                                   { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl } 
                                   } 
                                   { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } } 
                  }
              }
          }
          {
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { ##1 }
              {
                \msg_warning:nnn  { projlib-math } { operator-not-define } { ##1 }
              }
              {
                \bool_if:NTF #1
                  {
                     \exp_args:Nnf \use:n 
                                   { \exp_args:Nnc \use:n {\DeclareMathOperator*} {##1} } 
                  }
                  {
                     \exp_args:Nnf \use:n 
                                   { \exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathOperator {##1} } 
                  }
                  % This is the f-argument of  \exp_args:Nnf :
                  { \exp_args:NnV \use:nn 
                                  { \exp_stop_f: } 
                                  { \l__projlib_math_operator_style_tl } { ##1 } 
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \DefineOperator { s O{} m O{} }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
      {
        \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
      }
      {
        \projlib_math_define_operator:nnn { #1 } { #3 } { #2 }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\DefineOperator { id, Id, Ker, Image = Im } [ style = \mathsf ]

\DefineOperator*{ Lim, Max } [ style = \mathbf ]


\begin{document}

\( \id_A \)

\( \Lim_{n\to \infty} \)

\[
  \Lim_{n\to \infty}
\]

\[
  \Max_A
\]

\( \Id_A, \Image \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this idea! May I ask what is the purpose of `{~}` after `\use:nn`? To my understanding this is a placeholder for `\exp_args:NnV` to work on the `\..._style_tl`, but why not simply `{}`?

Comment: @Jinwen `~` is tokenized as an explicit space-token in expl3-syntax. Its purpose is ending f-type-expansion. Instead of `~` you can also use `\exp_stop_f:` which is an implicit space token. (f-type-expansion ends when an unexpandable token is found. If that unexpandable token is a space-token, be it explicit or implicit, it ends f-type-expansion and is discarded. f-type-expansion is like ```\romannumeral`^^@``` where things get expanded until it is clear whether the alphabetic constant that denotes the number 0 is trailed by *<one optional space>*.)